# Youtube API V3 - Playback Restrictions (php)

Tags: php, json, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was using youtube api V2 till last week and decided to upgrade my functions to V3 for quotas reasons.
I'm using the api on this website www.gumdust.com to share videos from youtube and to check every day if shared videos are still online, available on mobile, embedable, etc. (cron job wich was limited by quotas).
The problem I have is that since I change to V3 api, I can't find how to retrieve the playback restrictions I had with the V2 API.
I really need to know if video can be played on mobile device (syndicate) and if it has no country limitation (regionRestriction) for equity reason on my site.
I'm currently using the API with those parameters :

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=xxRp1zFxKBY&key=MY_API_KEY&part=snippet,contentDetails,status`

I'm not sure if it is the best way of doing but I think it is the lightweight one.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi all, I'm sorry for the bump, but I'm still in trouble with the API V3...can some one help me by anything ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are doing things right as per [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). What you are looking for are the [embeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) and [regionRestriction](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction) properties.

PS : I'm aware this question is old but since I stumbled upon it while doing my own research on the subject I thought I'd answer.